# Does this.focus() fire an FocusEvent?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

For pure Javascript (no jQuery) if I add a `FocusEvent` handler on an `HTMLElement` and then call a `focus()` programmatically on this very same `HTMLElement`, will the `FocusEvent` handler be called?

And how much does the answer depend on browser types?

From this [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focus_event) I would say: yes it is called but it won't bubble up the element hierarchy (like in jQuery).
Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did [this little repro on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-functional-boilerplate-16-13-1-4wtnkd) to trigger the focus, and you can see it is triggered. Here is the code :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import "./style.css";

const App = () => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    document.querySelector('.myInput').focus()
  }, []);
  return (
    <div  onFocus={console.log('Focused')}>
      <input type='text' onFocus={console.log('Hello')} className='myInput' />
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

When the page load, you can see the console.log being show in the console, which mean the event has been fired.
Yes is React, but it's still javascript behind, I don't think it changes the way it works.

It's just a basic behavior so I don't take a lot of risk saying it is the same behavior in every browser, even IE.

About the bubbling, The console also show the console.log from the onFocus of the parent div, so I would say yes it does bubble up, at least in react. I tried with focusIn and it bubbles up as well so.. I don't really know.

---

In pure js, like in this code :

```
<div onFocus="console.log('triggeredparent')">
    <input type='text' onFocus="console.log('Hello')" id='myInput' />
</div>

<script>
  const appDiv = document.getElementById('app');
  const myInput = document.getElementById('myInput')

  myInput.focus();
</script>
```

The event is fired, but does not bubble up neither with onFocus nor focusIn. Maybe I did something wrong.

For your question in comment, if the element already has the focus, in pure js, onFocus does not seems to trigger a focus event a second time. Here is the code I used to test it :

```
<div onFocus="console.log('triggeredparent')">
    <input type='text' onFocus="focusInput()" id='myInput' />
</div>

<script>
  const appDiv = document.getElementById('app');
  const myInput = document.getElementById('myInput')

  myInput.focus();

function focusInput(){
  console.log('hello');
  myInput.focus();

}
</script>
```

Hopefully it does not becuse you would fall in an infinite loop if you do something like that.

Here is [the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-btbazv?file=index.js) where I did my tests.

Comment: What if the element already has the focus, would it again trigger an FocusEvent?

Comment: I edited my anser to add this test. I also shared the stackblitz so you can do your own tests